# Consulta con comparación de fechas

Tags: java, string, date, calendar

Estoy tratando de comparar fechas, lo cual me ha salido en cierta medida. El problema  surge cuando la fecha a es mayor a la fecha b. Dejo la explicación, tengo mis tres variables:

```
private String fechaActualBanner, horaActualBanner;
private String fechaFinalBanner = "27/04/2021";
private String horaFinalBanner = "17:00:00";
```

Luego, creo el método para obtener y comparar las fechas:

```
    Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mesActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    SimpleDateFormat sdfFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfHora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try{
        if(fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10){
            fechaActualBanner = "0" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    + "/" + mesActual
                    + "/" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }else if(mesActual < 10){
            fechaActualBanner = fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    + "/0" + mesActual
                    + "/" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }else{
            fechaActualBanner = fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    + "/" + mesActual
                    + "/" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
        horaActualBanner = fechaActual.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                + ":" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                + ":" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        Date fechaInicio = sdfFecha.parse(fechaActualBanner);
        Date horaInicio = sdfHora.parse(horaActualBanner);
        Date fechaFin = sdfFecha.parse(fechaFinalBanner);
        Date horaFin = sdfHora.parse(horaFinalBanner);

        long obtenerDiferenciaDeDias = fechaFin.getTime() - fechaInicio.getTime();
        long segundosF = obtenerDiferenciaDeDias / 1000;
        long minutosF = segundosF / 60;
        long horasF = minutosF / 60;
        long diasQueFaltan = horasF / 24;

        long obtenerDiferenciaDeHoras = horaFin.getTime() - horaInicio.getTime();
        long segundosM = (obtenerDiferenciaDeHoras / 1000)%60;
        long minutosM = (obtenerDiferenciaDeHoras / (1000*60))%60;
        long horasM = (obtenerDiferenciaDeHoras / (1000*60*60))%24;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alerta_inicio_app, null);
        final TextView tiempoRestante = view.findViewById(R.id.tiempoRestante);
        final Button cerrar = view.findViewById(R.id.cerrarAnuncio);

        tiempoRestante.setText("Quedan " + diasQueFaltan + " día(s) "
                + horasM + " hora(s) "
                + minutosM + " minuto(s) para que finalice el banner.");
        cerrar.setOnClickListener(v -> anuncio.dismiss());
        anuncio.setView(view);
        anuncio.show();
```

Cuando la hora es, en este caso, menor a las **17:00:00 (horaFinalBanner)** el texto muestra correctamente la diferencia horaria. Ejemplo si el móvil tiene las **13:50:51** la diferencia se muestra como **faltan 3 horas 10 minutos 09 segundos**. En el caso de la fecha, también marca la diferencia correcta. Hoy es 18/04 al 27/04 faltan 9 días, lo muestra bien. Ahora, cuando la hora es mayor a las **17:00:00 (horaFinalBanner)** por ejemplo son las **18:05** el string arroja lo siguiente:

```
faltan
9 días 
-1 horas
-05  minutos
```

Lo cual es incorrecto, porque lo que debería mostrar sería:

```
faltan
8 días
23 horas
55 minutos
```

¿Alguien me podría guiar sobre como hacer que se vea de la forma correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución corrigiendo el código de la siguiente manera:

```
private String fechaActualBanner, horaActualBanner;
private String fechaFinalBanner = "27/04/2021 17:00:00"; //añadí la hora al String
private long initialTime; //cree un long 
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // cree un cowntdowntimer
```

Luego, cambié el formato:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Y modifiqué los long con los tiempos:

```
String resultadoFechaHoraSO = fechaActualBanner + " " + horaActualBanner;
Date fechaResultadoString = sdfFecha.parse(resultadoFechaHoraSO);
Date b = sdfFecha.parse(fechaFinalBanner);
long resultado = b.getTime() - fechaResultadoString.getTime();
long segundos =(resultado/1000)%60;
long minutos=(resultado/(1000*60))%60;
long horas=(resultado/(1000*60*60))%24;
long dias=(resultado/(1000*60*60*24))%365;
Log.d(TAG, "anuncio: " + dias + "/" + horas+":"+minutos);
```

Inicialicé el long:

```
initialTime = resultado;
```

Y luego apliqué el `countDownTimer`

```
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(initialTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int dias = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
                int horas = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                        - (dias * 86400)) / 3600);
                int minutos = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                        - (dias * 86400) - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
                int segundos = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                String countDownText = String.format("Faltan %2d Dia(s) %2d Hr(s) %2d Min %2d Seg para que finalice el banner.", dias, horas, minutos, segundos);
                tiempoRestante.setText(countDownText);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tiempoRestante.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            }
        }.start();
```